# Is there any way to make dig work behind a proxy?

Tags: networking, server

With my corporate proxy, `curl` and `wget` work fine, but `dig` and `host` don't.

How can I configure `dig` to use a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

curl and wget use http proxies, which do not help dig.

To use a proxy with dig, you need a DNS proxy.  Most DNS servers can do that by default.  Most likely, you need to find an internal corporate DNS server that supports recursion and use the dig @ option to specify that server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing a DNS server?

Something like:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 mydomain.org
```

Comment: Yes I have.  Unfortunately this doesn't work. Mostly because external DNS is all done beyond the proxy.

Comment: If your corporate proxy only allows http(s) traffic, then one possible solution would be a http tunnel. For this to work, you would have to setup a machine (server) outside of our corporate network . This page explains how to setup a http tunnel: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-install-httptunnel-on-linux.html